# How to remove brackets '[]' and comma from my output result?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My Python program is:

```
def remove(duplicate):
  final_list=[]
  for num in duplicate:
    if num not in final_list:
      final_list.append(num)
  return final_list
duplicate=input()
print(remove(duplicate),end="")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, you are printing the entire list, wich output is the [] and the commas.
You just have to print each element separately
 Like:

```
for elem in remove(duplicate):
      print(elem, end=" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.join` to convert the list to a space-delimited string as an output:

```
print(' '.join(remove(duplicate)),end="")
```